# ADC Amplifier Exhibiting Incorrect Behavior

Tags: amplifier, analog, adc

I am designing a system that incorporates the [ADC12DL040](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/adc12dl040.pdf) ADC. Page 27 of the datasheet gives the following example schematic for converting a single-ended signal into a 1V +/- 0.5V differential signal as required by the inputs to the ADC:
[image]

With the following table for the values of the unspecified resistors:
[image]

My signal input ranges from 0-0.5V, so I used the resistor values in the second row. I am trying to simulate the amp in LTspice with the following schematic:
[image]

However, the simulation produces the following output, rather than two 1V +/- 0.5V signals:
[image]

Any idea where the circuit is going wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something seems really out of whack with that table/ spec sheet... or else I am not getting how that thing interprets differential.

Note it says

> VCM, should be in the range of 0.5V to 2.0V and be a value such that the peak
>   excursions of the analog signal does not go more negative than ground or more positive than 2.6V.

And the signal difference should not exceed Vref = 1V

That makes the table plain wrong....

Try these...

R1 1500
R2 1500
R3 1500
R4 1500
R5 2500
R6 2500

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fblZOl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Comment: I knew something was up with the datasheet. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you look carefully you will realize that the non inverting input of U6 is connected to ground rather than a voltage divider as shown in the reference schematic, that may well be the cause of the unpredicted behavior

Comment: The table of resistor values says that one of the resistors in that divider should be zero ohms and the other should be open. Hence a zero ohm connection to ground and an open connection to 2V.